# Can I identify the distribution of a random variable given a related distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$, $X_2$ be i.i.d random variables.

Suppose we know the distribution function of $X:=|X_1-X_2| =\max\{X_1,X_2\} - \min\{X_1,X_2\}$.

Can we find the distribution of $X_1$?

I realize that to have any hope of identification we must fix the support of these random variables since $|X_1-X_2| = |(X_1+C)-(X_2+C)|$ for any constant $C$.

Considering first absolutely continuous random variables, with supports of the type $[a,b]$, or open ended intervals such as $[0,infinity)$, are there conditions under which the distribution of $X_1$ can be determined uniquely?

Thanks.

Comment: I would try using Bayes' formula, since finding the PDF of max and min (and also for the range) could be proposed using generalized extreme value (GEV) theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we find the distribution of $X_1$?

Not in general, even neglecting the translations you mention.

To see why, assume that the distribution of $X$ is known, then $X_1-X_2$ is distributed like $UX$ where $U=\pm1$ is a symmetric Bernoulli random variable independent of $X$, hence the distribution of $X_1-X_2$ is known, that is, $|\varphi|^2$ is known, where $\varphi:t\mapsto E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itX_1})$ is the common characteristic function of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Thus, to know the distribution of $X$ is equivalent to knowing $|\varphi|$. But, as is well known (!), $|\varphi|$ does not determine $\varphi$, hence  the distribution of $X$ does not determine the common distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

For a counterexample, assume that $\varphi$ has period $4$ and $\varphi(t)=1-|t|$ for every $|t|\leqslant2$ (equivalently, $\varphi$ is the characteristic function of the distribution $\frac4{\pi^2}\sum\limits_n\frac1{n^2}\delta_{n\pi/2}$ where the sum is over every *odd* integer, but the exact form of the distribution will not be needed). Now, $\psi:t\mapsto\frac12+\frac12\varphi(2t)$ is also a characteristic function and it happens that $|\varphi|=\psi$ since $\psi$ has period $2$ and $\psi(t)=1-|t|=\varphi(t)$ for every $|t|\leqslant1$. Thus, $|\varphi|^2=|\psi|^2$ although the corresponding distributions are not translations of each other.

Comment: Apologies for the very late response, but thank you very much for your solution!

Comment: The counterexample given here is for discrete random variables, could you perhaps come up with an example of two continuous random variables, with the same bounded support, and characteristic functions psi1, psi2, such that |psi1| = |psi2| but psi1 and psi2 do not coincide?

Thanks.

Comment: Why "with the same bounded support"? // Re continuity, one can add the same continuous distribution (say uniform on a small interval) to each discrete distribution of the example given in my post.

Comment: If the random variables are restricted to have bounded support one might think that identification of the initial distribution would be possible at one of the endpoints. // Thanks for your comment on continuity.